# Grammar - for you / with you?

Tags: grammar, phrases, descriptive-grammar, grammaticality

I am writing a letter and got stuck here:

Will that be alright for you? or Will that be alright with you?

Which one is the correct version?

Comment: _With_ is more common, but I don't see anything wrong with _for_ either.

Comment: [What @IsabelArcher said.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+that+alright+*+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20that%20alright%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20that%20alright%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0) But *Is that okay **by** you?* is also fine by me, and some native speakers may accept *other* prepositions. Including [*Is that okay **to** you?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+that+okay+to+you%22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will that be alright for you?

Here, the speaker wants to know whether something is *suitable for* you.

> Will that be alright with you?

Here, the speaker wants to know whether you *agree with* the speaker.

Comment: Is 'alright' considered acceptable now?

Comment: *"Alright"* is defined as a shortened form of the phrase *“all right”* and it means *okay* or *satisfactory.* (https://www.yourdictionary.com/alright)

Comment: Still a bit iffy, in formal writing. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/all-right-or-alright-which-is-correct)

Comment: Exactly! That sounds a bit iffy.